# Why isn't my left column div taking 100% height of it's parent div?

Tags: css, css-float, html

I looked at other examples on here, but nothing seems to work for my specific issue. I have two columns, a left and a right, floated left and right respectively. The left column is not taking 100% height of it's parent. I have height set on all parents and I tried min-height: inherit. I tried nesting a div to extend height. I'm not sure what else to try.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tUzJ5/6/

Comment: Which browser versions do you need to support? If you are OK excluding IE7 and earlier, then you can use `display: table-cell` on the two divs and they will automatically match height to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left column is set to `float:left;`, and height doesn't work like you think it will with floats.

Here's how I changed your CSS http://jsfiddle.net/tUzJ5/7/

Basically, make the left col `position: absolute`, and the wrapping `#wrap` DIV have `position: relative`.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That was quick and awesome. So I'll keep running into that issue with floats?